# Chrome doesn't show included html

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple html with included another html via jquery:

```
<!-- included.html -->
<ul>
   <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">Page 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myinc').load('included.html');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myinc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox+IE shows me the list but Chrome not (empty page).
Any solutions?

Many thanks

Comment: Cache issue maybe... Any error in console?

Comment: Do you have a server running on your localhost?

Comment: I have cleared all caches -> same problem

Comment: I marked it as dupe because obviously you don't know how to debug javascript. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is about chrome security features. If you run it from your local that is not work but if you work on server it will be work

Comment: yes, i run it from my local pc; are you sure it's a 'security ' feature?

Comment: yes it is about security

Comment: lol yes it's a 'security' feature.  otherwise I could say `.load('C:\...')` to read whatever I want off your HDD (assuming permissions on the user account had access).

Comment: Can you please add further details to your answer? On SO we share knowledge not only find solutions

Answer (score 1):

In the Chrome Console (Click F+12) you can see the error like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/...temp/included.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Chrome has web security.

The solitions may be:

1. Disable web security in Chrome

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

2. Or put you file into http server, and write a path to file

   $('#myinc').load('http://mysitedotcom/included.html');
3. Or run index.html using the local server.